# Store iteration count and then access it outside of for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I expect I'm misunderstanding how hoisting works but I'm confused by why returning i++ is not being hoisted up to the initial declaration of var i. For context I'm trying to create previous/next buttons that utilize scrollIntoView() to cycle between divs.

I have it working as intended for the next button (click and it cycles to next div) but the problem is I can't seem to store the current value of i outside the for loop so that I can use stepsTotal[i] inside another function (for handling the previous button on click).

Here is the code I have working for the next button (previous button function not included). I'm trying to get console.log(i) to print 0,1,2,3, etc. when the next button is clicked.)

```js
const stepsTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("question-steps");

const currentStep = (function() {
  var i;
  console.log(i); // How do I have this print the current value of i instead of undefined? (i.e. match the results of the second console.log)

  for (i=0; i<stepsTotal.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("next-button").addEventListener("click", scrollToCurrentStep);

    function scrollToCurrentStep() {
      stepsTotal[i].scrollIntoView(true);
      i++;
      console.log(i); // I want the first console.log to match this one
      return
    }
    return
  }
}());
```

Comment: Uh, the `console.log(i)` is getting you `undefined` simply because you haven't initialised the variable yet before the loop. If you put it inside the loop body, you will see multiple integers logged.

Comment: You are attaching multiple event handlers to the same button. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Do you mean move the console.log(i) inside the loop or initialize the variable? I am using console.log() here because I'm trying to be able to log the multiple integers  outside the for loop so I can use the current value of i in another function.

Thanks for the note about the multiple event handlers. The next button only works once if I pull it out of the for loop so I will have to do some more research on the best way to attach event handlers as I typically use onclick in the html.

Comment: Uh, you cannot log *multiple* integers without the loop?